# Parse PFPush - Increment badge not working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push using the client SDK on iOS.
Badge increment does not seem to do anything.
Is it because this property only works when sending push to channels?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"USERNAME == %@", user];
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:USER predicate:predicate];
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"message", @"alert",
                      @"Increment", @"badge",
                      @"default.wav", @"sound",
                      nil];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: I suggest opening this as a bug report on developers.facebook.com

Comment: Tried opening a bug report, but the bug reporting tool itself seems to not work for me. When I hit submit, nothing happens :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work now. Haven't changed anything in my code, not sure if it was just some bug in Parse which was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any notification at all when sending this? If not I believe it is because you are not setting up your query correctly for Installations and the notification is not being sent at all. When creating your query you need to do the following:

```
PFQuery* query = [PFInstallation query];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];  //  Or however else you have linked a user to your installations
```

Comment: I am getting notifications, also the notification sound works fine. Its just the "Increment" that does not work. If I hard code a value like "5" for badge, that also works fine.